# Извлечение из таблицы повторяющихся значений при выполнении нескольких условий

Tags: sql, cursor, db2

Как с помощью курсора при проходе по таблице при выполнении определённого условия записать в другую таблицу все записи над курсором, в которых по порядку повторяется значение в одном поле?

[image: Схема]

Допустим, есть подобная табличка. В ней поля отсортированы по полю `NOM_V`. Как средствами языка С и встроенного SQL при совпадении условий:

1) В соседнем поле выполнилось какое-то условие (например, оно содержит `NULL`)

2) Это последняя запись со значением `C` в поле `NOM_V`

организовать `INSERT` в другую таблицу всех записей, содержащих значение `С` в `NOM_VAG`. (в данном случае, записи `[4,5,6]`).

**upd.** Случай может быть не единичный. Требуется выбрать записи из всей таблицы, где данные условия совпадают. Т.е. если условие в `field1` выполнится в записи 9, то в добавок к `[4,5,6]` надо выцепить ещё и `[7,8,9]`. И так до самого конца.

Comment: А зачем тут вообще курсор? Зависит, конечно, от используемого диалекта SQL, но вообще говоря, такие вещи делаются одним запросом.

Comment: @Yaant Дело в том, что это далеко не единственное условие. Возможно, одними средствами SQL и можно было бы выбрать всё разом, но я пока неофит в этом деле, так что вряд ли у меня получится запихнуть всё в один запрос.

Comment: А вы это можете сделать курсором только если будете где то запоминать все пройденные записи, в массиве в памяти или вставляя во временную таблицу, а потом по соблюдению условия перенося все из временной таблицы. Так что одним запросом было бы предпочтительнее. И вас действительно DB2 SQL ? какая то экзотика ...

Comment: Хотя что то я перемудрил. временные таблицы не нужны. читаете свой запрос и вставляете записи, как только условие сработало просто выходите из цикла чтения. остается решить что делать если дочитали до конца а условие не сработало ...

Comment: @Mike А не вариант использовать `SCROLL`-курсор? Наверное, если не выйдет, буду с помощью массива решать задачу.

Comment: Лучше SQL подучите. первая задача реализуется тупо как `insert into ... select ... from B where nom_v in(select nom_v from B where filed1 is null)` со второй конечно сложнее, надо понять как D относится к C, но обычно это то же не особо большая проблема

Answer (score 1):

курсор нужен, т.к. нет явного поля, которое показывало бы, что именно эта конкретная строка является последней с этим NOM_V. Т.е. нужна информация и по предыдущей соседней строке (факт изменения значения поля NOM_V ) . 
Внутри блока курсора запоминать значение NOM_V и факт выполнения 'условия'.
А перед этим - проверить эти данные сохраненные на предыдущей итерации. И если NOM_V поменялось и было выполнено 'условие' - выбрать все строки с предыдущим значением NOM_V и перелить в новую таблицу. А только потом сохранять в переменных новое значение NOM_V и факт выполнения 'условия'.
После прохода курсора до конца при выполнении условия на последней строке (сохраненного на последней итерации курсора) - также перелить в новую таблицу строки с сохраненным последним NOM_V.
Конкретный синтаксис процедуры, думаю, тут не принципиален

Comment: люди, извините, не заметил что вопрос также помечен меткой db2. не уверен, что там 'курсор' - означает тоже самое что и в более современных типах баз данных